# Are the rings $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3+1)$ isomorphic?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $A=\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-1)$
>
> (a) Prove that $A$ is a direct product of two integral domains.
> (b) Is the ring $A$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3+1)$? Justify your answer.

I was guessing the first part will be isomorphic to direct product $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x-1\rangle$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2 + x +1\rangle$. But I cannot prove they are equal. I think here equality means in terms of isomorphism of rings. I will be happy if anyone helps me in solving this.

Comment: I think (a) is probably referring to $A$ being the internal direct product of two subrings which are each integral domains, rather than $A$ literally being equal to an external direct product of two rings.  (According to category theory, we don't really care much whether the second is true or not.)  The internal direct product statement would mean that the canonical map $B_1 \times B_2 \to A$, $(x, y) \mapsto x+y$, is an isomorphism.  Which I think would be equivalent to $B_1 \cap B_2 = \{ 0 \}$, $B_1 + B_2 = A$, and $xy=0$ whenever $x \in B_1, y \in B_2$.

Comment: Wait, actually not subrings strictly since that would require 1 to be in both - but subsets which are individually rings, with all the structure except 1 being inherited from the larger ring.

Comment: In the comments to the deleted answer by lhf, I suggested that the map $P(X)\mapsto P(-X)$ descends to an isomorphism of $A$ onto $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^3-1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show the isomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}/(X-1)\oplus \mathbb{Q}/(X^2+X+1)$ apply the Chinese remainder theorem, or use the fact that there exist polynomials $A$ and $B$ such that $A(X-1)+B(X^2+X+1)=1$ and  consider the canonical map $\mathbb{Q}[X]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X-1)\oplus \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2+X+1)$ and show that its kernel is the ideal generated by $X^3-1$.

Comment: I think u r using the notation of direct sum .but here it is given that it is direct product.

Comment: Do these notation mean same  here?

Comment: In the 2nd proof I cannit see where the fact X-1 and X^2 + X +1 is being used.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to (b) is affirmative. Here we give an explicit isomorphism.

Let $A=\mathbb Q[X]/(X^3+1)$ and $B=\mathbb Q[X]/(X^3-1)$. Define a map $T\colon \mathbb Q[X]\to \mathbb Q[X]$ by 
$$T(P)(X):=P(-X).$$ 
Clearly, $T$ is a ring automorphism. The restriction of $T$ to the ideal $(X^3+1)$ is a ring isomorphism of $(X^3+1)$ onto $(X^3-1)$, so the map $\tilde{T}\colon A\to B$ given by
$$\tilde{T}( P+ (X^3+1) ) := T(P)+(X^3-1)$$ 
is well-defined an it is a ring isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\gcd(X-1,X^{2}+X+1)=1$, so $(X-1)$ and $(X^{2}+X+1)$ are coprime, so Chinese Remainder Theorem applies, just as what @Tsemo Aristide has noted.

Comment: Will you explain little more?

Comment: Here Q[X] = (X-1) + ( X^2 + X +1) .Am I correct?